# How to obtain the Kernel Module Interface for my Android kernel?

Tags: kernel, android-13

I'm running Android 13 via crDroid 9.8 on my Pixel 7 Pro.

I want to try KernelSU, but in order to download the proper version, I need to know my Android kernel's KMI ("Kernel Module Interface"), and I don't know how to obtain this KMI value.

On the "Android version" page in Settings, it says that my kernel version is **5.10.157-ga88edbe37d3a**, but as far as I know, that isn't the KMI.

There are several KernelSU versions on the KernelSU site referenced by KMI's which start with "5.10.157", and I assume I should choose one of them. But without knowing my kernel's KMI, I don't know which one of those I should try.

How can I figure out my kernel's KMI?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**: To be clear, the KernelSU docs say that the kernel name should match the following pattern:

`Version.PatchLevel.SubLevel-AndroidRelease-KmiGeneration-suffix`

Then, the KMI would be `Version`.`Patchlevel`-`AndroidRelease`-`KMIGeneration-suffix`.

However, my kernel name is only this: `5.10.157-ga88edbe37d3a`, and it has no `AndroidRelease` field, and there are several KernelSU images there with "5.10.157" in their name.

This is why I'm posting my question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pixel 7 Pro device shipped with the android13-5.10 kernel. So you should pick the KMI associated with that kernel version. If the KernelSu KMIs are stable, then you should be able to pick the latest `5.10.*-android13-*` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly the info I've been looking for!